# USB stick showing in disks but not in files, I want to upload a document onto it

Tags: usb, files

USB stick showing in disks but not in files, I want to upload a document onto it...[image: disks]

[image: files screenshot]

[image: other locations]

Comment: The screenshots are pretty useless, why didn't you select the `16gb Thumb Drive` befor taking the screenshot, so we could see something...

Comment: Click on 'other locations' in 'Files'. It should show up if the usb stick is mounted.

Comment: hiya, I've updated the photos on the post so it shows "other locations" in files where it doesn't display my usb stick and the disk photo is also there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should show up if you mount it (e.g. click the 'play' symbol in disks).

TAILS sticks seem to not be auto-mounted when plugged in.
(I assume it is your stick and you are aware that there is TAILS OS installed on it. So it is not really meant to be used as external data storage - note, that the selected partition is read-only anyway).

Comment: Thank you, when I’m on tomorrow I will get an update and Yes, I was playing around with TailsOS so looks a bit odd to store important docs on the same USB and that’s interesting as well. Thanks again.

Comment: To store a document you'd first have to create a partition in the empty space and then mount THAT partition. This might, however, interfere with a persistent volume that you might want to setup inside tails (in case your tails is working - usually recent version use several GB, I wonder, why yours is so small).

Comment: Great, all is now solved. thanks for the help. Perhaps because I used an old version of TailsOS.

Comment: Good to hear! In case the answer helped solving the issue, you might consider accepting it by clicking the green check mark.